# Why Agda sometimes complains about the code it writes itself when you use a case split?

Tags: agda

I'm not sure what is a minimal replication of this problem, but [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/MaiaVictor/78411eae1910957d539501258709489c) replicates it. Notice the `preservation` function at the end of the file:

```
preservation : ∀ n Γ t t' T → t ~ t' → Γ ⊢ t ∷ T → Γ ⊢ t' ∷ T
preservation n Γ t t' T eq an = ?
```

If we ask Agda to case-split on `eq`, it writes this code:

```
preservation : ∀ n Γ t t' T → t ~ t' → Γ ⊢ t ∷ T → Γ ⊢ t' ∷ T
preservation n Γ .(app (lam _ _) _) .(subst (λ v → _) _) T ~β an = {!   !}
preservation n Γ .(app _ _) .(app _ _) T (~app eq eq₁) an = {!   !}
preservation n Γ .(lam _ _) .(lam _ _) T (~lam eq eq₁) an = {!   !}
preservation n Γ t .t T ~refl an = {!   !}
preservation n Γ t t' T (~sym eq) an = {!   !}
preservation n Γ t t' T (~trans eq eq₁) an = {!   !}
```

Which makes it fail to compile due to the following error:

```
Failed to solve the following constraints:
  [543] subst (λ v → _331 n Γ T an v) (_t_332 n Γ T an)
          = subst (λ v → .x) .f
          : Term (_n_321 n)
when checking that the given dot pattern subst (λ v → _) _ matches
the inferred value subst (λ v → .x) .f
```

This happens a lot and is extremely annoying. Interestingly, if I refactor the `~` type to not use implicits anymore, then trying to do the case-split again works! Seems like it is, thus, somehow related to implicit arguments. Why does this happen, and can I avoid it?

Comment: This looks like it is a bug in Agda, please report it on the [agda bug tracker](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/new)